# When using change_column_default on a column with no default, what should be the 'from' value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

This is my create table migration. Please note that I didn't provide the default value for `price`.

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to set a default value. According to [the Migration guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), I should provide `from` to make it reversible. What value should I provide?

```
class ChangeProductsPriceDefault < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_column_default :products, :price, from: 'WHAT_TO_WRITE_HERE?', to: 0
  end
end
```

Comment: write from: nil @wit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"No default" means default is NULL, so:

```
change_column_default :products, :price, from: nil, to: 0
```

There is a description about nil as default: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_default

Comment: I was tempted to use `null`. Can you tell me a bit more why it's `nil`, not `null`?

Comment: `null` is valid in only SQL, but `nil` only in ruby. Both means almost the same - no value.